# Como alterar objetos do URL via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho um sistema de busca no meu site usando o Google Custom Search, e para definir a pesquisa por imagens, é acrescentado no URL: `#gsc.tab=1`. Como eu crio um sistema em JS que pode ser executado via link que adiciona isso no URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tenho certeza se é isso que você está buscando, mas esse fragmento que começa com `#` é chamado de *hash* e pode ser obtido e alterado assim:

```
// pega o valor atual
var hashAtual = window.location.hash;

// troca o valor
window.location.hash = 'foo';

// monitora trocas de valor
window.onhashchange = function() {
    console.log('hash trocado para ' + window.location.hash);
}
```

Comment: Mas como eu linko essa função?

Comment: No onclick do seu link, simplesmente altere o hash usando a segunda linha do meu exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Para ler a `hash` que está no URL pode usar:

```
window.location.hash
```

A partir daí tem de retirar os valores que pretende com uma funcão como esta em baixo:

```
function getHASH() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);
    var pares = hash.split('&');
    var chaves = pares.map(function (par) {
        var chave_valor = par.split('=');
        return {
            chave: chave_valor[0],
            valor: chave_valor[1]
        };
    });
    return chaves;
}
```

Fica um exemplo que funciona apesar do jsFiddle não mostrar a HASH no url: http://jsfiddle.net/hym346sw/

O resultado do exemplo é:

```
"[
    {
        "chave": "teste",
        "valor": "10"
    },
    {
        "chave": "outro.Teste",
        "valor": "20"
    }
]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Você não pode simplesmente colocar esse código no próprio atributo `href` do link?

```
<a href="#gsc.tab=1">Pesquisar por imagens</a>
```