# Como abrir uma imagem em nova guia ao clicá-la e bloquear página sem parâmetro?

Tags: javascript

Estou com a pesquisa do CSE no meu site, e até fiz essa pergunta: [Como alterar objetos do URL via JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38850/como-alterar-objetos-do-url-via-javascript), e queria saber se tem como criar um script que as imagens da página abram em nova guia quando forem clicadas.

E queria que o usuário fosse redirecionado para a página inicial do site quando a página de pesquisa estivesse com o parâmetro `?q=` vazio (sem pesquisa).

Comment: Quanto mais detalhes você der na pergunta, mais fácil fica para responder de primeira. Mas, atenção, detalhes importantes, detalhes superfluos só atrapalham.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para abrir uma nova janela pode [ver esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3313/129). No fundo precisa de usar o `window.open('url da imagem')`, ou pode simplesmente usar o atributo `target="_blank"` no HTML usando no `href` da ancora o URL da imagem:

```
<a href="http://meudominio.com/minhaimagem.jpg" target="_blank">Texto ou Imagem aqui</a>
```

Para fazer o redirecionamento pode fazer assim (colocando dentro de tags `<script></script>` preferencialmente na `head` da página:

```
var query = window.location.search;
if (query == '?q=') window.location.href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: Blz. Precisa ter o Id das imagens?

Comment: @GustavoPonte depende de como o HTML está feito, e como faz o redirecionamento. Qual é o HTML que o utilizador clica? É uma ancora? `<a></a>`

Comment: Olha, eu sei que, quando são exibidos resultados de imagens e o usuário clica, em vez de abrir a imagem, abre um link. Veja: https://www.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=012244706173914607628:ivy1g9qzid0

Comment: E o "location.search", na verdade, o link de busca é:

Comment: E sobre o "locarion.search": O link de pesquisa do meu site é: www.site.com/busca/?q=pesquisa. O que eu faço?

Comment: @GustavoPonte coloque o javascript que dei na resposta dentro da sua página, ele vai ler o URL e fazer o redirecionamento.. Em relação a como abrir uma imagem respondi ao que perguntou na pergunta.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado, valeu!

Comment: Marquei! Valeu!!!